# VBA code to find and replace cell borders taking a LONG TIME

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to improve the below code so that it performs better.I am trying to find all cells in my specified worksheets that contain borders that aren't 'thin' and change them to a 'thin' line.

The below works, but it does slow my VBA code down a lot.

Thanks

```
    For Each j In ws.UsedRange.Cells
        For k = 5 To 10
        If j.Borders(k).Weight <> xlThin Then _
        j.Borders(k).Weight = xlThin
        Next
    Next
```

I've now tried the below, it seems a little better.  Screenupdating is already turned off.  Does anyone think I could make any further improvements to the performance???

```
       Set MyUsedRange = ws.UsedRange.Cells
        For Each j In MyUsedRange
             For k = 5 To 10
             If j.Borders(k).Weight <> xlThin Then _
             j.Borders(k).Weight = xlThin
             Next
         Next
```

Comment: what is j? what is k?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some other code we're not aware of, there's no need to set each cell separately and there's no need to check if it's NOT something before setting it to something...

```
For k = 5 To 10
       ws.UsedRange.Borders(k) = xlThin
Next
```

Comment: Oh hang on I see what you mean... so not all will have a border, but those that do you want them thin... hmm... 

Try setting "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" at start (and = true at end!), and try setting a range = ws.UsedRange before the For loop... perhaps there's some overhead in Excel working out what a "UsedRange" is every loop... but thats a stab in the dark I don't know if VBA would recalculate that object each time or not

Comment: Actually, it's still very slow.  Anyone else got any ideas how to improve this code?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Usedrange very large ?

```
 msgbox ws.usedrange.address
```

try this code:

```
Dim Rg as Range
set Rg = ws.UsedRange
Application.Screenupdating = False
with ws.Range(Rg.Address) 'Avoids a looping usedRange, in case it's updating itself , might also work by using a simple With Rg
    For k = 5 To 10
       .Borders(k) = xlThin
    Next k
end with
Application.Screeupdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it only apepars to change the top border for row A. Looking at "msgbox ws.usedrange.address" it returnes a range of $A$1:$AX$48 for the sheet.  Any ideas why it;s not changing the border for the rest of the rows?  Also, without doing an 

" If .Borders(k).Weight <> xlThin Then _
             .Borders(k).Weight = xlThin"

How does it know what to change?